# BTRFS install focal next to eoan

Tags: 19.10, 20.04, btrfs

I'm currently running Ubuntu 19.10 on btrfs. The following subvolumes are used

- @ /
- @home /home
- @no-snapshots /no-snapshots (VMs)

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside my current install on a new subvolume.

Planned steps:

1. rename @ to @eoan
2. change /etc/fstab
3. change grub config?
4. install Ubuntu to @focal and mount @home as /home

What changes are necessary for step 3?
Can I tell the installer to use @focal instead of @?